# Getting human readable date from Epoch into variable

Tags: linux, bash, epoch

Okay, this is probably a very basic question; but, I'm just getting back in the saddle with Linux.

I have a variable that hold an Epoch time called pauseTime.
I need that variable to become human readable (something like 2012-06-13 13:48:30).

I know I can just type in

```
date -d @133986838 //just a random number there
```

and that will print something similar.  But I need to get the variable to hold that human readable date, instead of the epoch time...  I keep running into errors with everything I'm trying.  Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well do this:

```
VARIABLENAME=$(date -d @133986838)
```

and then

```
export VARIABLENAME
```

or in Bash do directly:

```
export VARIABLENAME=$(date -d @133986838)
```

If you want formatting, say in the usual ISO format:

```
export ISODATE=$(date -d @133986838 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# or
EPOCHDATE=133986838
export ISODATE=$(date -d @$EPOCHDATE +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The formats behind the `+` are explained in `man date`.

Note: `$()` is the modern form of the backticks. I.e. catching output from a command into a variable. However, `$()` makes some things easier, most notably escaping rules inside of it. So you should always prefer it over backticks if your shell understands it.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried something similar...  But, following yours I realized that I never cleared out the variable at the end of my loop.  Causing it to error out on the next pass.  Thanks, that solves my problem.

Comment: why are you recommending that he export the variable?

Comment: Why are you exporting the variable. I'm almost certain it's not necessary. Does a child process need to see it? That would be the only reason to do so. Some people do this habitually and they shouldn't.

Comment: @jordanm: easy, because this is more versatile. I don't want that he ends up expecting the variable to be usable from some other context of which nothing is mentioned in the question. Sure, it's optional. But without more context I stand by my decision to recommend the `export` :)

Comment: @jordanm: very constructive. Way to go! You have asked me why I did it, I justified. You reply by downvoting without even a hint why you consider something "bad habit" that is common use everywhere. And if you haven't noticed the first code snippet is entirely without `export` (and that was also for a reason). But sure, have it your way.